# Create draggable text box for each line of text

Tags: windows, graphs, graphic-design

I have a list in a text document and need a program that can take each line and make it into a correctly sized text box (not too big or too small). It also mustn't add line breaks to any lines.

When I say text box I mean the sort of thing that can be dragged around, linked together by lines, and resized.  I am making an organizational chart so need this behavior.

Is there any software that can do this? I've looked at LibreOffice, Google Docs/Sheets and MS Office 2010 so far.

Comment: When you say textbox, I *think* you actually mean text with a black border?

Comment: this basically http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Microsoft-Office-Word-2007Images/Link_Text_Boxes___Select_Source_Text_Box.PNG

Answer (score 1):

If a programmatic solution is acceptable, [Essential Diagram for JavaScript](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/javascript/ejdiagram) supports creating any kind of diagram - organization charts are also supported. Typically org chart display elements are not editable, but that can be customized if needed (you can add Textboxes instead of labels)

[Example](http://js.syncfusion.com/demos/web/#!/azure/diagram/organizationalchart/university)

[image: Diagram JS organization chart]

I have linked to the JS version as it can be previewed inside the browser, but Windows Based versions for [WPF](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/wpf/diagram) and [Windows Forms](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/windows-forms/diagram) are also available.

The whole product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

I work for Syncfusion.